# get input type with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an 'input' dom element, and I need to check their 'type'.

the example code:

```
<form id='test'>
    <input type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaa">
</form>

var inputElement = document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Ok, now, I need to check if `inputElement` is type 'radio' or not.

How can I do that?

Comment: Refer documentations https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: `document.querySelector('#test input').type`

Comment: The content is generated after the dom was created, I can't use querySelector

Answer (score 2):

```
if (inputElement.type === "radio") {
    //Do something
}
```

If you block on things like that, I suggest learning some basic javascript, and reading [the DOM documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: I do not work with frontend, it's an exception and I'm not going to read lots of documentations. I tried it, I can't, I serch for it, I can't again... I ask here

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log(inputElement)
if(inputElement[0].getAttribute('type') === 'radio') console.log("It's a radio input");
if(inputElement[0].getAttribute('type') === 'text') console.log("It's a text input");
```

```html
<form id='test'>
    <input type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaa">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4pm9o6c/3/

```
<form name = 'test'>
  <input name="aaaa" type = "radio" value="aaa">
</form>

<script>
  var inputType = document.test.aaaa.type;

  if (inputType === 'radio') {
    alert(inputType);
  }
</script>
```

- Its convenient to use `<form>` using ***name*** attribute instead of ***id***.
- You didn't add any `<script>` tag to your JS code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
console.log(inputElement.attributes["type"].value)
```

```html
<form id='test'>
    <input type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaa">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jquery -

1. Give an ID to your input element -

   `<input type="radio" name="aaa" value="aaa" id="inputaaa">`
2. Get the type of your input in jquery as below -

   `var input_type = $("#inputaaa").attr("type");`
3. Check whether the input type is radio or not using jquery -

   `if(input_type == "radio"){// Your code if input_type is radio}
   else{// Your code if input_type is not radio}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var type = inputElement.getAttribute('type')
console.log(type)
```

```html
<form id='test'>
    <input type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaa">
</form>
```

Comment: using get getAttribute of an element